# "except InvalidThresholdMultiplierError" >> what does it mean??

Tags: python, matplotlib

So in this code that I'm experimenting with, I keep getting the same error...

Code :

```
import pylab
import numpy
from sp import ssim
from PIL import Image
ball = numpy.asarray(Image.open('soccer.png'))
other = numpy.asarray(Image.open('soccer2.png'))
ball_ssim = ssim.ssim(ball, ball)
other_ssim = ssim.ssim(ball, other)
pylab.figure()
pylab.subplot(2, 3, 1)
pylab.title('Original\n SSIM %.3f' % ball_ssim.mean())
pylab.imshow(ball, cmap=pylab.gray())
pylab.subplot(2, 3, 2)
pylab.title('Mean-Shifted\n SSIM %.3f' % other_ssim.mean())
pylab.imshow(other, cmap=pylab.gray())
pylab.subplot(2, 3, 3)

pylab.show()
```

The error that I keep getting is

```
line 68
except InvalidThresholdMultiplierError, e:
                                      ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Are there even 68 lines to this code? What does the error mean, and how do I fix this?

Comment: Is that the whole error message?

Answer (score 0):

That `Exception, variable_for_exception` syntax used to be valid in Python2. You must be calling a Python2 library using Python3. Be sure your versions all match up.

Specifically, check your version of `sp`.

Or, do all this in a Python2 context.